# output result calculate instantly php

Tags: php

I have a code here...the thing that i want is to calculate the total instantly and show in the textbox without clicking the action button.

code:

```
     <?php
        include('include/connect.php');
        if(isset($_POST['enter']))
        {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $score1 = $_POST['optA'];
        $score2 = $_POST['optB'];
        $score3 = $_POST['optC'];
        $score4 = $_POST['optD'];
        $total1 = $_POST['total'];
        $total = ($score1 + $score2 + $score3 + $score4);
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO score (name,score1,score2,score3,score4,total) VALUE ('$name','$score1','$score2','$score3','$score4','$total')");
        echo "succesful";
        }
        else
        {
        echo "you fail to execute!";
        }
        ?>
```

code:

```
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
    <input type="text" name="name"  />
    <input type="radio" name="optA" value="1" />1
    <input type="radio" name="optA" value="2" />2
    <input type="radio" name="optA" value="3" />3<br>
    <input type="radio" name="optB" value="1" />1
    <input type="radio" name="optB" value="2" />2
    <input type="radio" name="optB" value="3" />3<br>
    <input type="radio" name="optC" value="1" />1
    <input type="radio" name="optC" value="2" />2
    <input type="radio" name="optC" value="3" />3<br>
    <input type="radio" name="optD" value="1" />1
    <input type="radio" name="optD" value="2" />2
    <input type="radio" name="optD" value="3" />3
    <input type="text" name="total" value="<?php echo $total ?>" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="enter" name="enter" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Why don't you just do this with javascript

Comment: What would happen if one of your `$_POST` values contained this string: `-1 union select concat(version(),0x3a, database());`?

Answer (score 0):

PHP is executed before the content reaches the browser, so no elements will be loaded, so you cannot access them.  It is a **server-side** language, not **client-side;** therefore you cannot do this.  An example of something **client-side** is **Javascript.**  However, you can **create** a HTML element and set its attributes, then `echo` it onto the page.

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to use JavaScript in some form or another to not have to post the answer back to the server and wait for a response.

Here's how you can do it in JQuery.

```
function calculateTotal() {
    var total = 0;
    $('form input:radio:checked').each(function () {
        total = total + parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $('form [name=total]').val(total);
    return false;
}
```

In your HTML you'll need to change your submit button to something else like this:

```
<span onclick="calculateTotal()">Enter</span>
```